# Check that all bits are set except the Least Significant Bit by using masks

Tags: c, bit-fields

I'm just experimenting with bitfields in C(beginner).
Let's say I have an integer:

```
uint8 myBitfield
```

How do I check that all bits except the Least Significant Bit are set.

I thought this shall work:

```
if ((myBitfield & 0xFE) == 1)   // 0xFE = 0b11111110
{
/*yes all bits except the Least Significant is set*/
}
```

Any proposal?

Comment: Hint: try an example of a bitfield that should pass this, and see what you actually get when you AND with 0xFE.  You won't get 1...

Comment: The if instruction should be `if ((myBitfield & 0xFE) == 0xFE)`. You were not that far. Note that the last bit may be 0 or 1 with the test. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: if (myBitField == 0xFE) {} ensures that all bits except the LSB are set.  It is a bit doubtful that's what you actually meant.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote won't check what you expect

```
if ((myBitfield & 0xFE) == 1)   // 0xFE = 0b11111110
{
/*yes all bits except the Least Significant is set*/
}
```

More than that, the code inside the `if` block will never be executed because you clear the least significant bit (LSB) of `myBitfield` by the `& 0xFE` operation.

What you are looking for can be implemented by:

```
if (myBitfield == (uint8_t)~1)   // (uint8_t)~1 = 0b11111110
{
/*yes all bits except the Least Significant is set*/
}
```

Note that this is not the only way to implement such check. For example, it can also be written as

```
if (myBitfield == 0xFE)
```

or

```
if ((uint8_t)(myBitfield + 2) == 0)  // 0b1111110 + 0b00000010 = 0b1_00000000
```

and so on...

**EDIT**

If you meant that you want to check that bit 1 to 7 are set while bit 0 can be anything, you can then "force" this bit (bit 0) to be 0 and compare the result to the mask of all bits set from bit 1 to bit 7 (which is 0xFE):

```
if ( (myBitfield & 0xFE) == 0xFE)
```

Of course you also can check against all possible options without applying bitwise operations but the bitwise check looks better, in my opinion, and it also introduces better performance because it has a single branch while the example below contains 2 branches:

```
if (myBitfield == 0xFE || myBitfield == 0xFF)
```

Comment: This does not test whether all bits except the least significant bit are set. It tests whether all bits except the least significant are set and the least significant bit is zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Correct me if I am wrong but "How do I check that all bits except the Least Significant Bit are set." means that all bits are expected to be set except the least significant (which, as I understand, is not set).

Comment: The phrase excepts the least significant bit and states no requirements for it. Humans are imprecise and error prone, so the speaker could have intended the other meaning. However, if they had wanted to test whether the high seven bits were set and the lowest was not, they are asking to test that the bits are 11111110, and the obvious test is `myBitfield = 0xFE`. The fact that they attempted `myBitfield & 0xFE` is a further clue that they were attempting to consider the high seven bits separately and to neglect the low bit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have.

```
uint8 myBitfield2 = myBitfield;
```

<1> Shift the `myBitfield` 1 place to the right.

```
myBitfield2 = myBitfield2 >> 1;
```

This will cause the myBitfield2 to shift right and evict the least significant bit.

<2> Or `0x80 [0b1000000]` with the `myBitfield2`.

This will insert a 1 in the most significant place of the `myBitfield2`.

<3> Find Complement of the `myBitfield` by performing `myBitfield = 0xFF - myBitfield`.

Check if the complement is `0` then the original bitfield had all the bits 1 except the lsb. The lsb could be anything.

---

```
int bitField = 0xFF;
int bitField2 = bitField >> 1;
bitField2 = bitField2 | 0x80;
if(0xFF-bitField2==0){
    //All bits except the lsb is 1
}
```